# ¿Cómo mostrar datos según la categoría de una URL mediante switch case PHP?

Tags: php

Desde la ruta de una URL

```
mipagina.com/game/music/studio/this-is-my-favorite-music
```

Quiero mostrar contenidos cuando un usuario llegue a modificar la URL, manera:

```
mipagina.com/game/music/studio/
```

Si es es el caso quiero mostrar todos los contenidos que sean de `studio` es importante que se muestre los datos tomando en cuenta la ultima categoría.

Otro ejemplo:

```
mipagina.com/game/music/
```

Si ese es el caso, mostrar todos los datos sobre `music`

Como puedo hacer recorrer aquellos datos en un  `switch`

```
switch ($i) {
    case "studio":
        echo "";
        break;
    case "music":
        echo "";
        break;
    case "game":
        echo "";
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero valida que la url se estructura de la forma que quieres:

```
$uri     = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$isValid = preg_match('/([\w-]+)\/?$/', $uri, $matches);
if($isValid){
    // la acción que sea
}
```

Después la coincidencia la pasas al *switch*:

```
switch ($matches[1]) {
    case "studio":
        echo "Estudio!!";
        break;
    // ... case ...
}
```

Y lo pones todo en conjunto a trabajar:

```
// obtienes la url
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
// validas la url y capturas la última parte de la misma
$isValid = preg_match('/([\w-]+)\/?$/', $uri, $matches);
// si es válida pasas la captura al switch
if($isValid) {
    switch ($matches[1]) {
        case "studio":
            echo "Estudio!!";
            break;
        case "music":
            echo "Music!!";
            break;
        case "game":
            echo "Game!!";
            break;
    }
// si no es válida haces la acción que creas oportuna
} else {
    // accion si la url no es válida
    echo "No se encuentran resultados";
}
```

[Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/598fcf05a971745ba257a398fbe4902845819abe).
Solo cambia la url literal de la variable `$uri`.